# Alert message box

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

I have been using label text to show different status in an asp.net website.

e.g. "Profile Updates", "Invalid Character" etc, however would prefer to have a pop up message box instead.

This is what I have tried -

```
string alert = ws.webMethod(TextBox1.Text);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert(" + alert + ")</SCRIPT>");
```

However when this is fired, the screen in IE just seems to get bigger, and no message box is presented.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not advise doing this, it looks like you are creating a modal dialog on page load, meaning that your page cannot continue processing until a user has clicked OK.

That said, however, your problem is probably a lack of quotes around the `alert`ed text:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('" + alert + "')</SCRIPT>");`

Comment: Good input, however what would you suggest a better solution to handing prompts for the user?

Comment: You could use a jQuery modal (or similar), which would not halt execution. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Avoid popups as they just irritate the user, why have you decided not to go with a label? If you are going to display a message do one that doesn't prevent the page from loading. There are numerous javascript libraries for dialogs.  jQuery and Ajax Control toolkit would help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) instead of `Response.Write`

```
string alert = ws.webMethod(TextBox1.Text);
string script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert(" + alert + ")</SCRIPT>" 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "scriptBlockName", script );
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used this in my project, works fine for me

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "MessageBox", "alert('message')", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `alert` or you can use jquery plugin like [this](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) and [this](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).
if use jquery plugin you can custom message box like change backColor or...